# Which one is efficent way to integrate/merge second ios project in first one

Tags: ios

> Here i have go through many link that similar to my question but I
>   don't get satisfied answer. so here I have added my scenario.

I have two separate iOS projects. lets give label to `First` and `Second`.
now due to some scenario, I need `Second` project all features and views as well(example: Controllers, storyboard and business logic files) into `First` one. Both project are in larger size. Here I explore three different way.

1: Drag and Drop `Second` project to `First` one.

2: create static files of `Second` project.

3: create framework of `Second` project.

So kindly suggest me best efficient way to integrate `Second` project into `First` one so I can reduce source size to some extent and not need to manage `Second` project at two different places.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hereafter doing lots of work on this part and come to the conclusion that instead of managing two different projects. Make them one by following way.

> 1: Create Workspace.
>
> 2: Add Two different project into one.
>
> 3: Create a single pod for them if you want.
>
> 4: Whenever you want to access resource of another project, just added
>   them in compiler file list. by using this way you are managing single
>   file for two project. that can be applicable for multiple projects as
>   well.

By this way, only common resource shared and eliminate adding extra file by adding whole project as subproject.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create framework of second project. 
Move all files that i need in framework. 
And than import framework in first project.

Comment: but in that case, i need to maintain the project at two different places.

Comment: Only way that you will not maintain project at two different places is to cherrypick all files of interest from second project and put them in first.